# jQuery ajax loaded html not having proper css style after animate

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jquery-animate

I am using jQuery ajax to load html from a .html file.
The html file contains a two-column table form with both width 200px.
When I load the html content using $.ajax into a div, Google Chrome cannot show the proper css style which both column should be 200px width.
Firefox and IE10 correctly execute the correct css before the table is animated into the div which words in the first column are now in one row instead of two rows or more because of the small td.
However, when I click on either of the  tag inside the table, the table resized correctly in Chrome.

```
function test(){
$.ajax({
    url: "XXX.html",
    success: function(data){
        $("#main").css("position", "absolute");
        $("#main").css("left","200%");
        $("#main").html(data);
        $("#main").animate({left:"5%"},1000);
    }

})
}
```

Is it possible for Chorme to resize correctly before finished animating like Firefox and IE10?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
  function test(){
        $.ajax ({
   url: "XXX.html",
  success: function(data){
        $("#main").html(function(i,data){
        $("#main").css({'position':'absolute', 'left':'200px'});
        return data;});
$("#main").animate({left:"5%"},1000);
}
 });
  }
```

This should either work or go horribly wrong. I just learn Jquery! kinda. I also changed the 200 to px because thats what you referred to in your question. I am going to set up a wway to test this now but if you get to it first good luck!